# Зачем перегружать операторы, как свободные функции, а не функции-члены? C++

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Собственно, читаю про перегрузку операторов и наткнулся на два способа перегрузки операторов:

1. Как функция-член класса
2. Как свободная функция

Так вот сам вопрос, зачем перегружать операторы как свободные функции? Ведь из свободной функции мы не можем получить доступ к приватным полям без геттеров, разве этот способ не менее эффективный, для чего он нужен и в каких случаях его использовать предпочтительнее, чем перегрузка как функции-члена?

Comment: Ещё один случай - если это класс не ваш, а библиотечный, то вы просто не сможете определить оператор как член класса. Так бывает, например, с потоками данных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, простейший пример. Допустим, некий класс, скажем, для больших чисел длинной арифметики `Int`.

Если определим оператор `+` для обычных чисел внутри класса, то

```
Int a;
Int b = a + 2;
```

будет работать. А

```
Int a;
Int b = 2 + a;
```

уже нет. Потому что *первым* аргументом при операторе-члене всегда идет объект класса. Так что вы просто не сможете написать оператор, в котором первым идет *не* объект класса.

А для свободного - можно написать и так, и эдак...

Comment: Действительно... Спасибо за пример. Но разве использование операторов в качестве свободных функций не несет в себе скрытых опасностей вроде неявного преобразования типов или чего-то подобного?

Comment: Если писать аккуратно, конструкторы объявлять как `explicit`, например (ну, или наоборот - явно полагаться на неявные преобразования :) типов) - то ничуть не опаснее членов классов.

Answer (score 2):

Одна из причин по которой для бинарных операторов свободные функции могут оказаться предпочтительными — это симметрия. Часто желательно, чтобы если корректным выражением является `x@y`, то корректным выражением было бы и `y@x` для любых допустимых типов. Для свободных функций мы можем выбирать произвольный тип первого операнда, когда как в случае функции-члена мы этого лишены.

Как говорит С. Мэейрс, лучше делать функцию свободную, чем дружественную, так как свободная обычная функция дает гарантию неприкосновенности к внутренним сокрытым данным.